# Remove small words using Python

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible use regex to remove small words in a text? For example, I have the following string (text):

```
anytext = " in the echo chamber from Ontario duo "
```

I would like remove all words that is 3 characters or less. The Result should be:

```
"echo chamber from Ontario"
```

Is it possible do that using regular expression or any other python function?

Thanks.

Comment: I've added `echo` to your expected output, since it is 4 characters short. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- You may also want to change "less then 3 characters" to "less than 4 characters" -- just so the grammer is correct and it's all consistent.

Comment: @mgilson: I was a little more creative and made it *3 characters or less* instead.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Certainly, it's not that hard either:

```
shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,3}\b')
```

The above expression selects any word that is preceded by some non-word characters (essentially whitespace or the start), is between 1 and 3 characters short, and ends on a word boundary.

```
>>> shortword.sub('', anytext)
' echo chamber from Ontario '
```

The `\b` boundary matches are important here, they ensure that you don't match just the first or last 3 characters of a word.

The `\W*` at the start lets you remove both the word and the preceding non-word characters so that the rest of the sentence still matches up. Note that punctuation is included in `\W`, use `\s` if you *only* want to remove preceding whitespace.

For what it's worth, this regular expression solution *preserves* extra whitespace between the rest of the words, while mgilson's version collapses multiple whitespace characters into one space. Not sure if that matters to you.

His list comprehension solution *is* the faster of the two:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def re_remove(text): return shortword.sub('', text)
... 
>>> def lc_remove(text): return ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if len(word)>3)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('remove(" in the echo chamber from Ontario duo ")', 'from __main__ import re_remove as remove')
7.0774190425872803
>>> timeit.timeit('remove(" in the echo chamber from Ontario duo ")', 'from __main__ import lc_remove as remove')
6.4250049591064453
```

Answer (score 53):

I don't think you need a regex for this simple example anyway ...

```
' '.join(word for word in anytext.split() if len(word)>3)
```

Comment: Hmmm ... I think this one is my best chance at getting the populist badge thus far :)

Comment: WooHoo, Populist!  Thanks all -- Now you can start upvoting Martijn's answer again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of strings enter it in the str1 variable.

If you have a list, put it in the list_1 varible and delete the code above that variable.

```
def Convert(string):

    li = list(string.split(" "))
    return li
  
str1 = "Put list of strings to convert into a list here"
list_1 = (Convert(str1))

#Above is a string to list converter

def listToString(s):
    str2 = " " 
    return (str2.join(s))
    
anytext = (listToString(list_1)) 

print(' '.join(word for word in anytext.split() if len(word)>1))

#The number above is how many character of words you want to change
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of strings enter it in the str1 variable.

If you have a list, put it in the list_1 varible and delete the code above that variable.

```
def Convert(string):

    li = list(string.split(" "))
    return li
  
str1 = "Put list of strings to convert into a list here"
list_1 = (Convert(str1))

#Above is a string to list converter

def listToString(s):
    str2 = " " 
    return (str2.join(s))
    
anytext = (listToString(list_1)) 

print(' '.join(word for word in anytext.split() if len(word)>1))

#The number above is how many character of words you want to change
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this simply with this

```
re.findall(r'\b\w+\w{3,}\b', 'in the echo chamber from Ontario duo'))
```

the result is what you really want but note that this will give you a list not a string