# Python remove anything under 2 characters long

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings (As below format)

```
 ['email', 'go', 'a', 'instance', 'at', 'boo', 'email', 'message', 'message', 'instance', 'at', 'hello']
```

How can i eliminate anything under two characters long?

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12628958/748858

Comment: Can you post the desired result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

`new_list = [k for k in old_list if len(k) >= 2]`

List comprehensions are sometimes very convenient and easy to use, you can read more [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: the OP asked for under 2 characters long, you should edit your answer. `>=` to `<= 2`

Comment: @StephaneRolland The questioner asked for method to remove anything under two characters.

Comment: @StephaneRolland -- yours will only leave small words in the ouput -- That's not what OP wants (at least, that's not how I read the questoin) ...

Comment: @StephaneRolland, I think this will keep the words with length greater (or equal to) than 2.

Comment: You might want to [explain what a List Comprehension is](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: @arulmr you're right, I read wrong, that's for me to correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension is often the most readable:

```
myList = ['email', 'go', 'a', 'instance', 'at', 'boo', 'email', 'message', 'message', 'instance', 'at', 'hello']

myResultList = [x for x in myList if len(x) >=2]
```

[List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), is a mean to create a new list from iterating on another list.
In my exemple for each x in myList, the list comprehension keep x if len(x) <= 2.

you could also do things like:

```
myResultList = [x + "!oh" for x in myList if len(x) ==2]
```

that would results in `['go!oh','at!oh','at!oh']`