# Remove Words Less Than 4 Characters from Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, nlp

I am trying to remove all words with less than 4 characters from each scalar value in a Pandas Series. What is the best way to do it? Here is my failed attempt:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.join(word for word in df['text'].str.split() if len(word)>3)
```

I receive the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'join'

I based my attempt off of this post regarding the same in a string: [Remove small words using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628958/remove-small-words-using-python)

Side note: If its better to tokenize my words before removing with less than 4 characters please let me know.

EDIT: Each scalar value contains sentences so I want to remove for any words less than a length of 4 within the value.

Comment: I would consider accepting @piRSquared 's solution. It is more "pandonic", I feel like. It would be interesting to get some performance comparisons, though, and let the fastest win!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using regex with [`.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and [`.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) appears to be fastest:

```
df['text'].str.findall('\w{4,}').str.join(' ')
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["The quick brown fox", "jumped over the lazy dog", "foo bar baz", 'words exceeding desired length']})
df = pd.concat([df]*10**4, ignore_index=True)

def pir2(df):
    t = df.text.str.split(expand=True).stack()
    return t.loc[t.str.len() >= 4].groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join)
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit df['text'].str.findall('\w{4,}').str.join(' ')
10 loops, best of 3: 44.8 ms per loop

%timeit df.text.apply(lambda i: ' '.join(filter(lambda j: len(j) > 3, i.split())))
10 loops, best of 3: 79.3 ms per loop

%timeit df['text'].str.split().map(lambda sl: " ".join(s for s in sl if len(s) > 3))
10 loops, best of 3: 87.2 ms per loop

%timeit pir2(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.87 s per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["The quick brown fox", "jumped over the lazy dog"]})
>>> df
                       text
0       The quick brown fox
1  jumped over the lazy dog
>>> df['text'].str.split().map(lambda sl: " ".join(s for s in sl if len(s) > 3))
0         quick brown
1    jumped over lazy
Name: text, dtype: object
```

But honestly, I usually stick to vanilla python for text-processing pipelines. `pandas` data structures don't play well with text. At the very least, you are losing the memory/speed advantages of `numpy`/`pandas`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider @juanpa.arrivillaga's `dataframe` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["The quick brown fox", "jumped over the lazy dog"]})
```

Then we can

```
t = df.text.str.split(expand=True).stack()
t.loc[t.str.len() >= 4].groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join)

0         quick brown
1    jumped over lazy
dtype: object
```

Comment: Very nice, although, you till have to use `apply` :(.  I still maintain `pandas` is the wrong tool for text-preprocessing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what do you propose?

Comment: Vanilla python. Once you have a data-frame that is `object` dtype, you've given up the speed/memory efficiency of `numpy`/`pandas`. Sometimes that's OK because the "panel" abstraction is still useful, and there are a lot of handy routines built in to `pandas` data structures, but that really isn't the case for text. Most of my text-preprocessing occurs in vanilla Python, usually resulting in some sparse-representation that I feed into `sklearn` vectorizers to get featurized, sparse `numpy` arrays. But *if* I were going to use pandas, I'd choose this :)

Comment: Oh, and I always friggen forget about the `expand` argument to `pandas` split method!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga easy to do ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

`df.test.apply(lambda i: ' '.join(filter(lambda j: len(j) > 3, i.split())))`